# Got this Build time error when Building Unity iOS version 2019.3.0f1 with Vuforia 8.5.9

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, rubygems, cocoapods, vuforia

I got the below build time error when building for Unity iOS platform.  I am using 2019.3.0f1 with Vuforia 8.5.9.

iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions.

pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies

/usr/local/bin/pod install

CocoaPods : 1.5.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G4015)
       Xcode : 10.1 (10B61)
         Git : git version 2.14.1
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ d8b5f1b90922aae009a341d40e9247a63531eb11

```
### Plugins
```

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0

````
### Podfile

```ruby
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'

    target 'UnityFramework' do
      pod 'Crashlytics', '3.13.4'
      pod 'Fabric', '1.10.2'
      pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.2'
      pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.2'
      pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.2'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.14.0'
      pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.14.0'
      pod 'GoogleSignIn', '>= 4.0.2'
    end

RuntimeError - [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa.
If this attribute was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:321:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:262:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:262:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:262:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:203:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:103:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:918:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:917:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:917:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:912:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:78:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
````

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5B%21%5D+Xcodeproj+doesn%27t+know+about+the+following+attributes+%7B%22inputFileListPaths%22%3D%3E%5B%5D%2C+%22outputFileListPaths%22%3D%3E%5B%5D%7D+for+the+%27PBXShellScriptBuildPhase%27+isa.%0AIf+this+attribute+was+generated+by+Xcode+please+file+an+issue%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCocoaPods%2FXcodeproj%2Fissues%2Fnew&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

```
[33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`Unity-iPhone` UUID=`1D6058900D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `9D25ABA3213FB47800354C27` for attribute: `dependencies`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`Unity-iPhone` UUID=`1D6058900D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `31CF47E9BE796228AD5C0441` for attribute: `dependencies`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`Unity-iPhone Tests` UUID=`5623C57217FDCB0800090B9E`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `5623C58217FDCB0900090B9E` for attribute: `dependencies`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:91:in `block in validate_delegate': #<Pod::UserInterface::InspectorReporter:0x00007fa4ba036388> does not handle inspector_successfully_recieved_report (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:90:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:90:in `validate_delegate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:20:in `search'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:65:in `search_query'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:59:in `search_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:119:in `search_for_exceptions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:67:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

pod repo update output:

Updating spec repo `master`

CocoaPods 1.9.0.beta.2 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.9.0.beta.2

```
[33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[0m
```

#0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler::Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, core::basic_string >, Object*)
 #3 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

Answer (score 3):

Hi guys I found the solution for this problem.  It turns out to be cocoapods issue with mac Os. The solution is to execute the below commands from terminal.

$ gem uninstall cocoapods
 $ gem install cocoapods

You can found more details by following the below link

[Cocoapods Troubleshooting](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html)